# How to use hibernate session handling

Tags: java, hibernate

Can you give me an example code in java, how to use the hibernate session correctly? I want one controller class to handle all hibernate operations (fetch, update, delete).

```
  private void addPersonToEvent(Long personId, Long eventId) {
    Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
    session.beginTransaction();

    Person aPerson = (Person) session.load(Person.class, personId);
    Event anEvent = (Event) session.load(Event.class, eventId);
    aPerson.getEvents().add(anEvent);

    session.getTransaction().commit();
}
```

is this the correct way? how can i handle exceptions and the rollback correctly to avoid connection pool errors, may if connection was not closed correctly after an exception?

Thank you very much

Comment: try and catch exception.. if exception happen then transaction.rollback

Comment: If only it was documented... wait! http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.2/manual/en-US/html_single/#transactions-demarcation-nonmanaged

Comment: after that session.close() in finally block?

Comment: http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.2/manual/en-US/html_single/#transactions-basics check this out.

Answer (score 0):

> I want one controller class to handle all hibernate operations (fetch,
>   update, delete).

You should have an super class to handle all common operation(fetch, update, delete). The super class should be like:

```
public abstract class AbstractFacade<T> {
    private Class<T> entityClass;

    public AbstractFacade(Class<T> entityClass) {
        this.entityClass = entityClass;
    }
   public void create(T entity) {
    getSession().save(entity);
   }

  public void edit(T entity) {
    getSession().merge(entity);
  }

  public void remove(T entity) {
    getSession().remove(entity);
  }

  public T find(Object id) {
    return getEntityManager().find(entityClass, id);
  }
}
```